# How to combine a lists of two lists with a list of two lists of lists of varying length?

Tags: list-manipulation, code-request

This is probably asked before but I don't know how to begin searching for it.

**Some context:** I'm using `TemporalData` objects that share a number of common features but also have distinct characteristics. I use their `MetaInformation` to catalog these features for future reference. The output of the desired function will be used as the second argument in `Rule[Metainformation, #]`.

**I'm trying to accomplish the following:** given a list of common *keys* and *values* (`common:{keys_, values_}`) and another list consisting of two elements namely a list of *lists* of distinct *keys* and another list of *lists* of their corresponding distinct *values* (`unique:{allKeys_, allValues_}`) I want to produce a list of *lists* of rules where all lists of rules will contain both the common and the corresponding distinctive features.

*An example*: Assuming `f` is the desired function, then

```
in = {
  { {"a","b","c"}, {1,2,3} },
  { {{"d"}, {"e","f"}, {"g","h","i"}}, {{4}, {5,6}, {7,8,9}} }
 };

f @@ in
```

is expected to produce `out`, where `out` is defined as follows:

```
out = {
  {"a"->1, "b"->2, "c"->3, "d"->4},
  {"a"->1, "b"->2, "c"->3, "e"->5, "f"->6},
  {"a"->1, "b"->2, "c"->3, "g"->7, "h"->8, "i"->9}
 }
```

(Please note that the number of elements in the lists of `common` and the corresponding elements in the lists of `unique` is expected to be random. I used the example above just for ease of exposition.)

I have developed 3 function versions that seem to do what I want but they all feel a bit clunky; also, I think they are *too* similar. Furthermore, only the second one is a *proper* function.

If there are any suggestions on the presented code or-better yet-if there are any other ideas on how to code `f`, that would be great!

#### Some `f`'s

- **1.**

  ```
  f[common:{keys_, values_}, unique:{allKeys_, allValues_}] := 
    h[Apply[g /* List, common], Thread[Apply[g, unique]]]
  ```

  and

  ```
  {out} === (f[Sequence @@ in] /. h[x__] :> 
   Outer[j /* (Thread[#, g] &), x] /. {j -> Join, g -> Rule /* Thread})
  ```

  evaluates to

  > ```
  > True
  > ```
- **2.**

  ```
  f[common:{keys_, values_}, unique:{allKeys_, allValues_}] := Outer[
    List /* Transpose /* Apply[Rule /* (Apply[Join, #, 1] &) /* Thread], 
      {common}, Transpose[unique], 1]
  ```

  and

  ```
  {out} == f @@ in
  ```

  evaluates to

  > ```
  > True
  > ```
- **3.**

  ```
  f[common:{keys_, values_}, unique:{allKeys_, allValues_}] := 
    Apply[Rule][Thread[g[common, unique]]]
  ```

  and

  ```
  out === (
    ( f @@ in /. g[x_, y_] :> ReleaseHold[
        Distribute[Hold[Join][{x}, y], List]
       ] ) // Thread /* Map[Thread]
   )
  ```

  evaluates to

  > ```
  > True
  > ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3]
f1 = Catenate /@ Thread[MapThread[Thread@*Rule] /@ #, List, {2}] &;

f2 = Join @@@ Thread[MapThread[Thread@*Rule] /@ #, List, {2}] &;

f3 = Association @@@ Thread[MapThread[Thread@*Rule] /@ #, List, {2}] &;



f1 @ in
```

> {{"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, "d" -> 4}, {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, 
>      "c" -> 3, "e" -> 5, "f" -> 6}, {"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 3, 
>      "g" -> 7, "h" -> 8, "i" -> 9}}

```
Normal[f3 @ in] == f2 @ in == f1 @ in == out
```

> True